# SQL COLLATE DATA TO COLUMNS

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have the following query that returns a car reg number together with the date it was seen and the location:

```
SELECT PLATE_READ.RegNumber, PLATE_READ.DateSeen, ANPR_CAMERA.Name FROM PLATE_READ

REG         DATESEEN               LOCATION
===         ========               ========
5897HHS     20/12/2013 12:10:57    EXIT
5897HHS     20/12/2013 12:05:03    ROAD2
5897HHS     20/12/2013 12:01:17    ROAD1
```

Rather than having three rows i would like to be able to query and have 1 row returned per registration number stating the dates it has been seen per location with the following format:

```
REG         DATESEEN_EXIT        DATESEEN_ROAD2         DATESEEN_ROAD1
===         =============        ==============         ==============
5897HHS     20/12/2013 12:10:57  20/12/2013 12:05:03    20/12/2013 12:01:17
```

This is what i have so far:

```
SELECT  *
FROM (
select TOP(100) PLATE_READ.DateSeen, PLATE_READ.RegNumber, ANPR_CAMERA_GROUP.Name
from  ANPR_CAMERA INNER JOIN
                     ANPR_CAMERA_GROUP ON ANPR_CAMERA.Id = ANPR_CAMERA_GROUP.Id INNER     JOIN
                     ANPR_CAMERA_IN_GROUP ON ANPR_CAMERA.Id = ANPR_CAMERA_IN_GROUP.ANPRCameraId AND 
                     ANPR_CAMERA_GROUP.Id = ANPR_CAMERA_IN_GROUP.ANPRCameraGroupId INNER JOIN
                     PLATE_READ ON ANPR_CAMERA.Id = PLATE_READ.CameraId
ORDER BY PLATE_READ.DateSeen DESC
) x
pivot (
max(DateSeen)
for Name in ([GIB EXIT], [AIRPORT BARRIER])
)p
```

However this is always returning a NULL value for the 'GIB EXIT' entry

Comment: This is called a pivot query, so your question is undoubtedly a duplicate of other questions on this topic (depending on the database which is not tagged).  The one question is whether you always want three columns or whether the three columns vary depending on the values of `location` in the data.  If the latter, search for "dynamic pivot".

Comment: How does your question related with the `LINQ` and `.NET`?

Comment: i have improved the question and added what i have so far, which is doing what i what but is always giving me a NULL value for the first column 'GIB EXIT'